# namespaces and imports - have I got this right?

Tags: python, import, namespaces

Can someone please confirm that I'm understanding namespaces as they apply to imports please, ideally with some good references?

What I think happens is the following:

- I start a program either as a script or a module and it establishes a 'root' for the namespace
- I can `import packageX` providing `packageX` is located directly below the root or
- I can `import packageX.packageY.packageZ` for sub-packages
- From `packageZ` I can `import ..packageA` where package A and package Z are at the same level below `packageY`
- I can use relative namespaces but cannot go 'above' `packageX`; at best I can import from a package at the same level as `packageX`.

If I've got this correct, is there a way to see what 'level' in the namespace tree I'm at  e.g. if at `packageX` I have one level up possible or at level '' I can't got up any further?

This has had me tied in knots for the last few days and I'm not sure whether I'm looking at someone else's bugged code or my own misunderstanding!

Comment: have you read this : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages ? it has a good exemple. You need a  `__init__.py` at least on your root level if you only have one depth.

Comment: Thanks.  I currently have to use Python 2.6/2.7 but proving this works the same way, that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for and it's far clearer than anything else I'd found.

Comment: good. Most of the time, official doc is the best doc. 
It does work the same way. I don't beleive there is any difference there between python 2 and 3

Comment: If I've understood things correctly, what was tripping me up is that '.' means 'up one level' and not, as one might use for pathnames, '..'.  So I can have...
'''
from ...somewhere import something
'''
which is a little strange to see at first :-).